# Installing Big Integer libraries for C++?

Tags: c++

I try to install https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/ and even when I include all the .hh files, using BigIntegers throws undefined reference errors.

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `BigInteger::BigInteger(int)'
[Linker error] undefined reference to BigInteger::divideWithRemainder(BigInteger const&, BigInteger&)
```

I am using DevCPP and don't want to switch from this (it's been a headache getting anything other than DevCPP working). I also tried GMP but that was needlessly confusing and I couldn't get that working either.

When I tried compiling the `.cc` files that came with it, I get all the same linker errors.

Comment: [Linker error] undefined reference to `BigInteger::BigInteger(int)'

Comment: Have you tried using gmpxx? That's a C++-wrapper around the GMP numeric types, which is pretty self-explanatory to use (since it overloads the builtin operators to offer the interface of the "normal" numeric types).

Comment: That undefined reference error means that you're including the header files (definitions) for BigInteger, but not linking against the library actually implementing the BigInteger type.

Comment: @modelnine Not sure what gmpxx is. Is it simple to use?

Comment: @modelnine: If he can't get GMP working, he probably can't get the wrapper working either.  The `mattmccutchen` library is slow, but designed to be amazingly easy to install and use.

Comment: How do I "link against the library"?

Comment: @WhatsInAName gmpxx is the C++-wrapper provided by GMP (out of the box) - similar to the interface of BigInteger (from what I saw then looking at the BigInteger homepage), but based on gmp itself. See http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface

Comment: modelnine: The mattmccutchen library isn't precompiled, so he has to compile it, not link against it.  @WhatsInAName: Put the `.c` files from his library with yours, and compile them along with your files.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my reading comprehension skills failed me there.

Comment: How do I fix this undefined reference to BigInteger thing?

Comment: In CodeBlocks at least, everything works when it's all in a project and I add all of the .hh and .cc (excluding the sample and test) to the project and just include `bigintegerlibrary.hh` in my main file. Are you doing that in your project? Of course that's where linking to libraries actually comes in more useful.

Comment: How do I add them to my project?

Comment: There should be an option when going to project options or even just right clicking on the project, but I'm not exactly sure for DevCPP. I hate to admit it, but I've never used makefiles and I think a makefile might be the key for not having to include everything into each project you make.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how DevCPP works, but what you have to do is copy the `.c` files from Matt's library and put them in the same folder as your code (`.cpp`?) files.  Then you have to compile those files, in the same way that you compile all your code.  That should fix that problem.  The way to do this is compiler specific, but I found instructions for DevCPP here: http://www.uniqueness-template.com/devcpp/  Apperently you need to make a "project", and then add both your code and his code to it.  That's how you do programs with more than onen source file, which is absolutely essential knowledge for writing virtually any program.

You mentioned that your demo test code has the wrong answer, and that the code is

```
BigInteger num = 123456789*123456789*123456789;
```

This is because you have the integer `123456789`, and multiply by the integer `123456789` (which overflows), and then multiply by the integer `123456789` (which overflows _again), and *then* convert that result to a `BigInteger`.  Obviously, that's not right.  Your code should probably look like this:

```
BigInteger first = 123456789; //yes, you can convert from int to BigInteger
BigInteger second = 123456789;
BigInteger third = 123456789;
BigInteger num = first *second *third;
```

Since you want to convert from `int64_t` to `BigInteger`, you have to jump through a small hoop, as `BigInteger` was not designed with `int64_t` in mind.  So here's a conversion function.

```
BigInteger int64_to_BigInt(int64_t v)
{ return BigInteger(int(v/INT_MAX))*INT_MAX+int(v%INT_MAX);}

int64_t BigInt_to_int64(BigInteger v)
{
    BigInteger bottom;
    v.divideWithRemainder(INT_MAX, bottom);
    return int64_t(v.toInt())*INT_MAX + bottom.toUnsignedInt();
}
```

Comment: I already tried this -- it just threw endless lists of undefined reference issues

Comment: @WhatsInAName, Give an example of the undefined reference errors introduces by compiling and linking the library files.

Comment: @BenVoigt The Big Integer link I provided above has an archive with a bunch of .hh and .cc files. I put it all in the folder with my program, a .cpp file. At the top of my .cpp file I #include all the .hh files. I also try opening up the .cc files to click "compile" but they all throw reference errors. Simply running the .cpp with the includes throws the reference issue I mentioned in the original post

Comment: Stuff like   [Linker error] undefined reference to `BigInteger::BigInteger(int)' ,   [Linker error] undefined reference to `BigInteger::divideWithRemainder(BigInteger const&, BigInteger&)' , etc, list goes on. It's huge. Pretty much everything referring to anything BigInteger in the files.

Comment: @WhatsInAName: I edited your question with information that you _keep putting in chat instead of in the question_, and then edited my answer appropriately.  Please keep this question out of chat.  If you have further questions, either edit this question, or _make a new question on the SO site_.